# Como imprimir diretamente sem abrir a caixa de diálogo do navegador?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, impressão, impressora

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web onde preciso imprimir uma etiqueta e um comprovante não fiscal após o envio de um determinado formulário. Para realizar esta ação, possuo duas impressoras:

- Impressora Não Fiscal Matricial MP-20 MI - Para o cupom não fiscal;
- Impressora Térmica Zebra TLP 2844 Não Fiscal - Para a etiqueta;

Eu até consegui fazer a impressão utilizando a DLL [php_printer](https://pecl.php.net/package/printer) do PECL com php, mas não estava funcionando da forma como eu precisava: a impressão trava, as vezes envia e não imprime nada. É bem instável!

Tentei fazer a utilização da biblioteca [escpos-php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) e na impressora Matricial funcionou corretamente, porém na impressora Zebra ela não imprime o texto que eu envio.

Ví que é possível realizar uma configuração no navegador (Somente Firefox) para que o usuário consiga imprimir sem abrir a caixa de diálogo, mas para isso o usuário precisa realizar uma configuração no navegador e é possível utilizar somente uma impressora e não duas, conforme minha necessidade.

Por questões de compatibilidade não posso ter um applet java na máquina.

Não posso utilizar VBScript ou ActiveX, pois não posso forçar o usuário a utilizar somente um navegador específico.

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer essa impressão com PHP, Node.js ou javascript?

Comment: Se fosse uma impressora "comum" existe o comando "print" do proprio Windows, que poderia executar com "exec()", seria algo do tipo `exec("PRINT [/D:device] [[drive:][path]filename[...]]");`, não achei um link de documentação oficial. Pode ser que exista algum outro software de CLI para imprimir documentos mais complexos, como por exemplo o http://www.doc2prn.com/, nunca testei, mas só um exemplo.

Comment: `window.print();` não resolve?

Comment: Não, pois `window.print()` irá abrir a tela padrão de impressão do navegador.

Comment: Seria `CTRL SHIFT P`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resposta direta: **Não, não é possível.**

Imagine-se que fosse possível, você visita um site sem querer começa imprimir coisas indesejáveis em sua impressora sem sua permissão, já imaginou?

Quem comanda a impressão é o browser, é client-site, PHP não tem nada haver com isso. A menos que você queira comandar algo imprimir no server-site, que é onde o PHP roda, ou seja, mandar imprimir em alguma impressora que esteja conectado no servidor do server-side, mas, imprimir no client-side sem uma permissão não é possível.

Precisa entender a diferença entre **server-side** e **client-side**. O php é interpretado no **server-side** e mostrado para o **client-side**. Mandar imprimir através de um comando **shell** ou **exec** irá comandar no **server-side**.

Answer (score 0):

No Firefox:
abra uma aba e digite: about:config
clique com o botão direito e vá em Nova preferência > Boolean
cole este código: print.always_print_silent
na tela seguinte selecione True
Feito estes passos, toda vez que você receber uma impressão ela será enviada diretamente para a impressora.
Aí surge outro problema: o Mozilla Firefox mantém como padrão a última impressora que você utilizou nele.
Para resetar esta opção, ainda na aba about:config:

procure a opção: print.print_printer
clique com o botão direito e vá em Restaurar o padrão
Ainda não acabou! Na próxima impressão o Mozilla vai armazenar novamente a impressora utilizada.
Para que ele sempre utilize a impressora que é padrão do seu computador:

procure a opção: print.save_print_settings
dê dois cliques com o botão esquerdo do mouse para que altere seu valor para False
a linha selecionada ficará em negrito
Bom, agora você não vai mais ver a janela de confirmação de impressão e o
Mozilla Firefox sempre irá utilizar a impressora que está definida como padrão no seu computador.
Se você alterar a impressora padrão não será necessário reiniciar o navegador para utiliza-lá.

Answer (score -2):

Você consegue imprimir direto da aba de um navegador se:

- você tiver uma interface de comunicaçao direta com a impressora, exemplo:

  - um nodejs com um client socket conectado a um socket num host na nuvem.
  - um nodejs com serialport e conectado com a impressora.
- da aba do navegador voce envia um comando pro socket, onde o nodejs ficará escutando, ao ler a mensagem, imprime.